# How can I get sound working on my Powerbook G4 15" running Debian 8.6?

Tags: debian, audio, powerpc

I have recently switched from Ubuntu 12.04 to Debian 8 as support for 12.04 is about to run out. I tried Lubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu Mate 16.04 and Lubuntu 16.04 but couldn't get any of them to run in live mode for any length of time. I have installed Debian 8.6 LXDE and the install went ok and most things work, I have also managed to get Wifi and Bluetooth working but sound has me stumped. Alsamixer opens but shows no sound card.
Using terminal I get:

```
#:~$ aplay --list-devices
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

and :

```
#:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
--- no soundcards ---
```

Sound works in OSX and worked in Ubuntu 12.04.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post the contents of your kernel `dmesg` log? Is the `snd-powermac` driver module loaded?

Comment: Or perhaps the `snd-aoa-*` modules, for a PowerBook....

Comment: dmesg log is empty. How can I check if these modules have loaded.

Comment: The `dmesg.log` file may be empty, but just run the `dmesg` command to get the kernel log. The `lsmod` command will list loaded modules.

Comment: Running the sudo modprobe snd-aoa-i2sbus seems to have detected the right soundcard. Now I just need to get it working! Its seems to be using the snd-aoa-* drivers.

Comment: Can you tell me which repositories you used?

Comment: debian contrib and nonfree, I am not sure what worked in the end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Non-Free Firmware

If it worked in Ubuntu, but not in Debian, it was probably enabled by some non-free firmware package.

You may need to enable Debian's Non-Free repository in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and do `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get install whateverthefirmwarepackageyouneedhere`.

---

This is often the reason that hardware (like Wifi cards) don't work in Debian, but *do* work in other Linux distributions.

In many ways, Debian values freedom over something working like it's supposed to.

Comment: AFAIK, none of the powermac audio drivers require external firmware loads.

Comment: I just tried installing firmware-linux-nonfree. It didn't fix the sound on its own but also made the desktop freeze randomly as in Ubuntu. I then purged it and things returned to normal.

Answer (score 1):

The two responses above were helpful and I am not totally sure what sorted it but it seems like the following 2 steps helped:

1) Adding the non-free repository as recommended by Hydraxan14

2) Running sudo modprobe snd-aoa-i2sbus

3) Setting the soundcard to SoundByLayout in alsamixer

Sound is now working, Thank you so much!

Comment: Having said that, I can't seem to get the settings to happen at every boot up, I have to run the sudo modprobe snd-aoa-i2sbus command every time I want sound. I have added it to the usual boot-up and .profile files but so far no joy!